# Dropbox API: detect file updates, and get a URL to a file?

Tags: dropbox

I want to detect updates to files, as well as retrieve a URL to them.

Can that all be done through the Sync API? Or do I have to use both the Sync and the Core APIs? (Is that even possible?)

Thanks!

Comment: To get the updates, it is much better to use Sync API and to get the URL to a file, use Core API..

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following method to observe to changes all files in a folder

```
-[DBFilesystem addObserver:forPathAndChildren:]
```

Answer (score 0):

The Sync API doesn't currently support getting a public URL for a file (like the /shares endpoint in the REST API), but that feature will be coming in a future version.